# linux - serial port programming ( ASCII to Byte )

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I tried to receive data from serial port. However, those data is unrecognized to me. The root cause is because those are in ASCII. To decode the data, it needs to be the byte formate.
[image]

The buffer I've created is `unsigned char [255]` and I try to print out the data by using

```
while (STOP==FALSE) {  
        res = read(fd,buf,255);
        buf[res]=0; 
        printf(":%x\n", buf[0]);
        if (buf[0]=='z') STOP=TRUE;
     }
```

Two questions here:

1. The data might is shorter than 255 in the real case. It might takes 20 - 30 arrays from 255. In this case, how can I print 20 arrays ?
2. The correct output should be 41542b ( AT+ ) as the head of the entire command since this is the AT command. So I expect the buf[0] should be 41 in the beginning. It is, however, I dont know why the second one is e0 while I expect to have 54 (T).

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You're only printing the first byte out of 255...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ascii is a text encoding in bytes. There's no difference in reading them, it's just a matter of how you *interpret* what you read. This is not your problem.

Your problem is you read up to 255 bytes at once and only ever print the first of them.

It's pointless to set `buf[res]` to `0` when you expect binary data (that possibly contains `0` bytes). That's just useful for terminating *text strings*.

Just use a loop over your buffer, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < res; ++i)
{
    printf("%x", buf[i]);
}
```

Comment: Right, the print function in my code should work correctly. Can you let me know how to print out 255 bytes every time the data arrives ?

Comment: Note that usually, it wouldn't be pointless to terminate the string. It is just that this protocol format here is some obscure non-standard mix between ASCII and binary. Typically, AT commands are always followed by pure ASCII.

Comment: Sure, I didn't even think about the protocol in use, it's just *pointless* based on the OP writing he expects "bytes" (which I read: binary data). Of course it's the right thing to do for ascii strings.